# How do I successfully implement viewpager and recyclerView migrating from activity to fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Am following the udacity android basic nanodegree course and to implement recyclerView viewPager we are instructed to move code from activity to fragment, I have followed the instructions but when I run the app, It crashes before it even displays the first page and my debugger point me to a line(line 18) in the MainActivity.java file which is setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
I have done all fixes I could find on stack overflow and other tutorials I found but nothing seem to work for me. I have no idea what else to do. Help out. Pls

```
package com.example.tournaija;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find the view pager that will allow the user to swipe between fragments
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        // Create an adapter that knows which fragment should be shown on each page
        CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set the adapter onto the view pager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

this is the xml layout of main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.tournaija.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

the adapter

```
package com.example.tournaija;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;


/**
 * {@link CategoryAdapter} is a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that can provide the layout for
 * each list item based on a data source which is a list of {@link Place} objects.
 */
public class CategoryAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    /**
     * Create a new {@link CategoryAdapter} object.
     *
     * @param fm is the fragment manager that will keep each fragment's state in the adapter
     *           across swipes.
     */
    public CategoryAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /**
     * Return the {@link Fragment} that should be displayed for the given page number.
     */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return new HotelsFragment();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return new RestuarantsFragment();
        } else if (position == 2) {
            return new StadiumsFragment();
        } else if (position == 3) {
            return new MuseumsFragment();
        } else {
            return new MallsFragment();
        }
     }

    /**
     * Return the total number of pages.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

one of the activities and corresponding fragment with xml

Activity

```
package com.example.tournaija;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HotelsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new HotelsFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
package com.example.tournaija;


import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HotelsFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<Place> placeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public HotelsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_list, container, false);
        placeArrayList.add(new Place("Radisson Blu Anchorage Hotel, Lagos",
                "Situated in the heart of Lagos, Nigeria, Radisson " +
                        "Blu Anchorage Hotel, is a stunning masterpiece styled " +
                        "by famous Swedish hospitality designer, Christian Lundwall. " +
                        "The Radisson Blu Anchorage Hotel, Lagos, Nigeria is nestled " +
                        "along the Lagos Lagoon on Victoria Island in the midst of the " +
                        "business district and banking area. This Lagos hotel has " +
                        "170 air-conditioned rooms, including 8 unique and opulently " +
                        "furnished suites, offering both stunning city and lagoon views. " +
                        "The Voyage buffet-style restaurant serves a range of eclectic, " +
                        "international cuisine and local dishes, while overlooking " +
                        "the Lagos Lagoon. The View bar lounge is ideal for snacks and " +
                        "drinks, and perfect for a Classic Cocktail as the sun sets. " +
                        "Providing jetty access, the Surface Bar and Grill on the terrace " +
                        "offers outdoor dining overlooking the lagoon. Guests enjoy free " +
                        "access to the hotel fitness area, complete with cardiovascular gym, " +
                        "massage room, outdoor infinity swimming pool, and steam room.The hotel " +
                        "boasts two upscale boardrooms and four spacious meeting rooms, all " +
                        "offering natural light as well as all the modern, audiovisual " +
                        "equipment expected of a World Class Hotel. All you need for " +
                        "a successful stay!",
                R.drawable.radisson_blu));

        PlaceAdapter placeAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(getActivity(), placeArrayList);
        ListView placeList = rootView.findViewById(R.id.place_layout);

        // hooking the adapter
        placeList.setAdapter(placeAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/place_layout"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `Fragment` in `MainActivity.onCreate()` already... else these fields will be members of the `MainActivity` and not of whatever `Fragment`, as it is commonly supposed to be. Besides, using `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` in the XML is non-sense.